# django + ldap3 error on prod envirounment

Tags: python, django, ldap

Please help, i have next issue.
I have django 1.8 (python 3.3.5, centos 7) app with ldap authentication through external MS AD server. On my local dev envirounment everything is working fine and it is possible to authorize in the app, but after migration to the prod with Apache server it fails with Error permission denied.
I am using ldap3 with django-python3-ldap https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

Error:

```
DAPSocketOpenError at /login/
('unable to open socket', [(datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 14, 53, 5, 22728), <class 'ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError'>, LDAPSocketOpenError('socket connection error: [Errno 13] Permission denied',), ('172.20.48.12', 389)), (datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 14, 53, 5, 23125), <class 'ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError'>, LDAPSocketOpenError('socket connection error: [Errno 13] Permission denied',), ('172.20.48.11', 389))])

 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py in open, line 136
```

Connection line from the exception:

```
Connection(server=Server(host='ldap.server.corp', port=389, use_ssl=False, get_info='NO_INFO'), user='COMPANY\\user', password=u'value_password', auto_bind='NO_TLS', version=3, authentication='SIMPLE', client_strategy='SYNC', auto_referrals=True, check_names=True, read_only=False, lazy=False, raise_exceptions=False, fast_decoder=True)
```

When i start the app on dev django server - it is working fine, but when i run it through the apache it fails.
I can share any details if there is such need.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to SELinux permissions. httpd is unable to create the socket to connect to the LDAP. There is no need to disable SELinux completely.

First do a check with

```
getsebool -a | grep ldap # check SE booleans
```

You should see

```
authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap --> off
dhcpd_use_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
```

Set the boolean with the following command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap 1 #-P turns sets the boolean permanently (persist across reboots)
```

End result

```
authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap --> off
dhcpd_use_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> on
```

Answer (score 1):

With which user are you running Apache? probably it can't open sockets. Also if you're using wsgi check the user that run the python interpreter.

Comment: apache:apache user, i have fixed this issue by disabling of SELinux.